# ListView contained in a CardView is not showing full length

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-cardview, android-cards

I have a listview inside of a cardview, and although the height it set to wrap_content, it doesn't expand to fit the full size of the listview. It only displays the first item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/rootCardView"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#FEFEFE"
android:layout_margin="8dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/textPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/card_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>

    <!-- Main ListView -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/cardsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_below="@+id/card_title">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

It works if I set a definite size for the height of the card, but that isn't useful as the listview size will change often. Is there any way to have the card correctly show the whole listview?

Comment: set height to match_parent

Comment: why you are using cardview for listview

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about if you set a `android:minHeight` attribute ?

With this you will still have the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` but you will also have the minimum height you want to see.

Hope it helps.